# Unexpected results with async in c++

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, asynchronous

I am approaching parallel programming in C++ and, as I am working with functions which return a value, I decided to use `std::async` with `future` objects. In particular, I am parallelizing an integrator. I have a function `integrate(const std::vector<double>& v, double h)` which computes the integral under the function stored in `v`.

I first tried the function with a long vector and recorded the time, then I divided the vector in three subvectors and integrated simultanely the three different subvectors. However, the second time is always longer than the first, and this is not possible. What am I doing wrong?

```
double a;

const clock_t begin_time1 = clock();
a=integral(v1, h);
cout << double( clock () - begin_time1 ) /  CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;

future<double> f1, f2,f3;
const clock_t begin_time2 = clock();
f1 = async(launch::async, integral, ref(sv1), h);
f2 = async(launch::async, integral, ref(sv2), h);
f3 = async(launch::async, integral, ref(sv3), h);
cout << double( clock () - begin_time2 ) /  CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;

cout << a << "  " << f1.get()+f2.get()+f3.get() << endl;
```

EDIT: 
I solved it. clock() gives the CPU time, I needed of course the real time. 
steady_clock() did the job.

Comment: Why do you think "this is not possible"?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], including compile flags -- I mean, the above code times the async befoere it finishes the tasks!  Also, mandatory downvote for a performance question without compiler optimization flags: almost every C++ question on performance has someone asking for that, failing to provide it before being asked shows insufficient research.

Comment: Did you have to copy the whole vector into subvectors? Why not just use three sets of `begin/end` iterators into different portions of the same vector?

Comment: Measuring time AFTER all get()s will be more conclusive.

Comment: melpomene: The time of the integration (and of basically almost any function taking vectors as argument)  is proportional to the vector lenght. How is it possible to take more tine if the vector is three times shorter?

Comment: Yakk: yes, the time is token before the .get. This makes the question even more interesting, how can start three routines of lenght l take more tine than performing an entire routine of lenght 3l? About the flag, I looked for async, and I didn't find anything similar. You are free to link it.

Comment: Galik: that is not the point. It is just a test code for an header, the vextor creation is not an issue

Comment: You might want to embrace `auto`.

Comment: Deduplicator: Might you explain yourself with more words?

Answer (score 0):

It takes longer to **start 3 threads** than it takes to run your calculation.

Comment: Yes, but I tried to run the test with different and long vectors (10^7-8 elements), which where stored after some non negligible time. Considering that I forced the passing by reference, it is even more nonsense that starting three threads is longer than entirely performing a three times longer one.